# Sending mail from localhost in laravel

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

I am trying to send mail from localhost using `smtp.gmail.com` in laravel but am getting this as response

```
No IDN encoder found (install the intl extension or the true/punycode package
```

I have configured everything correctly, How do I solve this

Comment: you configuration need this `package`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by enabling `;extension=intl` by removing `;` in php.ini